# Searched everywhere but cannot run my own sample bash script with crontab

Tags: linux, bash, cron

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#!/bin/bash 
#!/bin/sh
filename='/home/supersaiyan/sample1.sh'
for i in 1 2 3 4 5
do
  echo "String $i"
  x1+="String"$i
done
echo "#Added string is: $x1" >> $filename
echo "The following string has been added to the file: $x1"
```

Here's the bash script I created which runs fine when using the bash command. It doesn't work in crontab though.

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
5 * * * * echo '#tanginamo cron tester' >> /home/supersaiyan/samplerz.sh
* * * * * /bin/bash /home/supersaiyan/sample1.sh
```

Here's what I put in crontab. The first line is just for testing and is working fine so I'm really lost on why the second one isn't working.

EDIT: Tried removing the SHELL and PATH lines to no avail
The .sh file is already modified as executable

Comment: Does `/bin/bash` exist?

Comment: I think it does, but how do I make sure of that? Sorry, just started trying to learn the ropes awhile ago.

Comment: You're saying that `/bin/bash /home/supersaiyan/sample1.sh` in a terminal causes the file to successfully append lines to itself, but it doesn't work from cron?

Comment: Yes. To clarify, when I'm in the terminal and I run bash /home/supersaiyan/sample.sh the script works fine and does what it should which is append lines to itself. In cron, the script itself doesn't seem to work at all as I'm seeing no activity.

And yes. The first line is working. I see new lines appear in /home/supersaiyan/samplerz.sh

Comment: Er, `ls /bin/bash`?

Comment: It does. I am able to run the script normally through terminal.

Comment: Standard first troubleshooting step is to capture output & error messages from the script by adding something like `>>/tmp/sample1.log 2>&1` at the end of the crontab entry. Let it run, then check the log to see what happened. BTW, having multiple shebang lines (the `#!` ones) in the script does nothing useful; only the first line is actually used.

Comment: I see I see. I was searching furiously on some solutions and stumble upon those shebang lines in my script. I did try them 1 by 1 but still none worked, then I tried putting all of them and still didn't work and I just left them there since they don't seem to conflict with anything. 

I'll try your suggestion. Do I need to create the .log file or will it be created automatically?

Comment: The log file doesn't populate which makes me think the line doesn't work at all.
I put it in like this:
     * * * * * /bin/bash /home/supersaiyan/sample1.sh >> /tmp/sample1.log 2>&1

Comment: How do you edit the crontab?

Comment: I type in crontab -e, and then make the changes. Also, update about the log file. Not sure how but it suddenly worked, but it says /bin/sh: 1: cannot fork

Comment: `* * * * *` tells cron to run this script every minute!  So you eventually reach a `cannot fork` situation since you probably have a ton of these scripts that run!  To test, just put something more specific.  Like `5 * * * *`.  It will run once per hour, when minutes == 5.  Change the number to something close to what time it is right now.  The idea is to execute it once!  Also in crontab, if sample.sh is executable, you do not need to put `/bin/bash`.  The `#!` line will take care of this.

Comment: And ... wait a second...  Your script is modifying itself ?!?  You are adding lines in the script as it runs?  Since these lines you are adding are not valid bash code, it will work 1 time.  Then all subsequent executions will fail with something like `1: command not found`...

Comment: And your last `echo` is not sent to a file.  So cron will take that output and send it to your user via an email.  Avoid `echo` in cron, or send the output to some log file.  Same for the `echo` in the loop.

Comment: Haha yes, the script is appending lines to itself. Was just following instructions given lol. I was told to create a script that appends any string to itself using any loop condition, and then have a crontab that runs it every 5 mins. So far it hasn't run even once in crontab, but runs no problem in the terminal. Oh and to make sure the lines being appended don't alter anything I made sure to put # before each line that it's going to apepnd to make them comments. (I think that's what it does?)

echo "#Added string is: $x1" >> $filename

Comment: Should I replace the 'echo' in the script to printfs?

Comment: What does _It doesn't work_ mean?

Comment: Ok. That question made me wonder. I seem like I was under the impression that the crontab is supposed to execute the script on the terminal so I continuously monitored the terminal and since nothing was showing, I thought it wasn't working. When I checked the file again several lines have been added, which I assume is because the crontab is working, but I just didn't know that it was not supposed to work as if I ran the script from the terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your output should be going to a different file than your actual script file.

You need to change :

```
filename='/home/supersaiyan/sample1.sh'
```

to:

```
filename='/home/supersaiyan/sample1.out'
```

...and run the script again.
You may want to review it's contents past line 10 or so.
Enjoy! :)